# XML in C# - adding namespace to a new XML element

Tags: c#, xml, ssis, xml-namespaces

The XML I post may be big, but my problem is rather simple. Please take a look at the second Dimensions tag. The first Dimension is automatically generated. The second one is created by me in C# script. 
The question is: how do I make my Dimension tag have the exact same namespaces ("xsi:type="RegularMeasureGroupDimension") as the generated one? 
Thanks for any help!

This is the C# code I use to generate the Dimension:

```
XmlNode dimensions2 = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[6].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[5];
            dimensions2.AppendChild(dimension2);
        //dimension2.SetAttribute("xmlns","http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine");
           // dimension2.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XmlSchema-instance");
            dimension2.SetAttribute("type", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XmlSchema-instance", "RegularMeasureGroupDimension");
```

And this is the XML file:

```
<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <ParentObject>
    <DatabaseID>test_szymon</DatabaseID>
  </ParentObject>
  <ObjectDefinition>
    <Cube xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400">
      <ID>Test</ID>
      <Name>Test</Name>
      <Annotations>(...)</Annotations>
      <Language>1033</Language>
      <Collation>English</Collation>
      <Dimensions>(...)</Dimensions>
      <MeasureGroups>
        <MeasureGroup>
          <ID>FAKT</ID>
          <Name>FAKT</Name>
          <Measures>
            <Measure>
              <ID>Miara1</ID>
              <Name>Miara1</Name>
              <DataType>Integer</DataType>
              <Source>
                <DataType>Integer</DataType>
                <Source xsi:type="ColumnBinding">
                  <TableID>dbo_FACT</TableID>
                  <ColumnID>measure1</ColumnID>
                </Source>
              </Source>
            </Measure>
            <Measure>
              <ID>FACT</ID>
              <Name>FACT</Name>
              <AggregateFunction>Count</AggregateFunction>
              <DataType>Integer</DataType>
              <Source>
                <DataType>Integer</DataType>
                <DataSize>4</DataSize>
                <Source xsi:type="RowBinding">
                  <TableID>dbo_FAKT</TableID>
                </Source>
              </Source>
            </Measure>
          </Measures>
          <StorageMode>Molap</StorageMode>
          <ProcessingMode>Regular</ProcessingMode>
          <Dimensions>
            <Dimension xsi:type="RegularMeasureGroupDimension">
              <CubeDimensionID>WYMIAR</CubeDimensionID>
              <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                  <AttributeID>Id Wymiar</AttributeID>
                  <KeyColumns>
                    <KeyColumn>
                      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
                      <NullProcessing>UnknownMember</NullProcessing>
                      <Source xsi:type="ColumnBinding">
                        <TableID>dbo_FAKT</TableID>
                        <ColumnID>id_wymiar</ColumnID>
                      </Source>
                    </KeyColumn>
                  </KeyColumns>
                  <Type>Granularity</Type>
                </Attribute>
              </Attributes>
            </Dimension>
<Dimension d7p1:type="RegularMeasureGroupDimension" xmlns:d7p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XmlSchema-instance">
              <CubeDimensionID>WYMIAR2</CubeDimensionID>
              <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                  <AttributeID>Id Wymiar2</AttributeID>
                  <KeyColumns>
                    <KeyColumn>
                      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
                      <NullProcessing>UnknownMember</NullProcessing>
                      <Source xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XmlSchema-instance" xsi:type="ColumnBinding">
                        <TableID>dbo_FAKT</TableID>
                        <ColumnID>id_wymiar</ColumnID>
                      </Source>
                    </KeyColumn>
                  </KeyColumns>
                  <Type>Granularity</Type>
                </Attribute>
              </Attributes>
            </Dimension>
          </Dimensions>
```

Comment: How are you generating the XML?

Comment: From an *information* perspective, they are the same. Namespace prefixes are only ever locally defined within an XML document, and more than one prefix may reference the same namespace.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever they need to be exactly the same - this is the only way this XMLA query gets processed

Comment: Are you sure? Because anything that's processing XML using decent libraries (rather than by string mangling) should just reach that attribute and know that it's the `type` attribute from the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XmlSchema-instance` namespace.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - yes I am sure- when I try to process this query in SQL Server the error appears saying that the namespace cannot appear in this node

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`XmlDocument.CreateAttribute(prefix, localName, namespaceURI)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs2zzesf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which allows us to specify prefix of the attribute, for example :

```
var attr = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "type", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XmlSchema-instance");
attr.Value = "RegularMeasureGroupDimension";
dimension2.SetAttributeNode(attr);
```